# Text preview boxes are jumbled in Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, text

When I hover over text or links in Google Chrome the text boxes are jumbled. I don't quite know how to describe it, it just looks weird and that's why I figured I'd show you some pictures:

[Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PczPN.jpg)

This doesn't happen every time, but is easily reproducible.
My graphics card is Nvidia Geforce GTX 950M.

Answer (score 0):

we're still waiting on amd to release a new AMDPRO GPU driver that works with ubuntu 17.04 if and when they do it should fix this issue (which i also have. BTW it ony does this on first hover. if you hover it again you get to see the actual thing)

an update on ubuntu's stock amd driver is also much needed from canonical/the linux community.

also please specify what grapics card model you have exactly.

if you have ubuntu 16.04 or under then head on over here : http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx

see if your graphics card is supported and if it is horray!

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot. I edited my answer and added the specs as a picture.

Comment: well that allowed me to know you are on ubuntu 16.04 but i still don't know what graphics card you have.

Comment: I thought it was in the specs but apparently not. Changed it.

Comment: then your on nvidia and this is thus a systemwide 17.04 issue that isn't caused by one either nvidia or AMD. I don't know that there is a solution for this (yet!) and am as interested as you are in any eventual fix. you should add a bounty on your question.

Comment: But I'm not using 17.04. Ok. Thank you :) It doesn't bother me that much, I just wanted to know if there was a solution.